# How to display SQL query on leaflet map

Tags: javascript, php, json, leaflet

I have an issue with my leaflet map, I want to display an SQL query but it doesn't work. I put the result in a JS variable like this:

```
<?php

 $connect = connect();
 $req_ch = "SELECT json_build_object(
   'type', 'FeatureCollection',
   'crs',  json_build_object(
       'type',      'name',
       'properties', json_build_object(
       'name', 'EPSG:4326')),
   'features', json_agg(
       json_build_object(
           'type',       'Feature',
           'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::json,
           'properties', json_build_object(
               'name', code_chambre,
               'sro', zone_sro
           )
       )
   )
 ) AS objet_geosjon FROM tvx_chambres;";

 $result_ch = pg_query($connect, $req_ch);

 $rs_ch = pg_fetch_array($result_ch);

 $geo_ch = $rs_ch[0];

 ?>

var g_ch = <?php echo $geo_ch;?>;
```

Then I tried to display it with this query:

```
$.getJSON(g_ch, function(data) {
    var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
        }
    });
    var map = L.map().fitBounds(geojson.getBounds());
    geojson.addTo(map);
});
```

I used `console.log(g_ch)` and I saw my geoJson on my browser console and there is no error on it.
Do you have an idea of what could I do for solve my problem?

Comment: `$.getJSON(g_ch` makes no sense if `g_ch` is already an object. $.getJSON exepcts a URL as the first parameter, so it can go and get some JSON data from the server - see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ to know this. Since you already echo'd the JSON into the `g_ch` javascript variable as an object literal, you can just use this variable directly in your code. I don't know the geoJson function specifically, but I would guess you would do something like `var geojson = L.geojson(g_ch...` (and remove all the $.getJSON stuff).

Comment: Great, I added it as a proper answer below, so you can go and upvote / mark it as accepted. That way, it will show in search results for others who may have a similar issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`$.getJSON(g_ch...` makes no sense if `g_ch` is already an object. `$.getJSON` exepcts a URL as the first parameter, so it can go and get some JSON data from the server - see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON to know this.

Since you already echo'd the JSON into the `g_ch` JavaScript variable as an object literal, you can just use this variable directly in your code. I don't know the geoJson function specifically, but I would expect you need to do something like

```
var geojson = L.geojson(g_ch...
```

(and remove all the $.getJSON stuff, of course.)